# Trouble tokenizing for binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree, tokenize

I am trying to tokenize a textfile and then put the tokens in a binary tree where the token that has a lower value goes on the left branch of the tree and the token that has a higher value goes to the right and repeated values have an updated count. The problem that I am having is that whenever "fgets" gets a new string line from the textfile, it changes the top of the binary tree to the first token of the new string. It basically creates a new binary tree instead of continuing on to the original binary tree which is what I want. I believe the problems lays somewhere in the way I am tokenizing the text file.

The function "insert" does all the calculations for the binary tree.
The function "addNode" adds the first token of the textfile to the top of the binary tree.

sample textfile:

two seven eight ten

nine five zero

eight

ten one

```
    int main(void)
    {
        char buffer[100];
        char *del = " ";
        char *token;
        struct node* root = NULL;
        int i = 0;

        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
        {
            token = strtok(buffer, del);

            if(root == NULL)
            {   
                printf("add: %s\n", token);
                root = addNode(token);    
            }

            else
            {
                insert(root, token);
            }


            while(token != NULL)
            {   
                token = strtok(NULL, del);

                if(token != NULL)
                    insert(root, token);
            }

        }

    }

void insert(struct node* root, char *token)
{


    if(strcmp(token, root->word) < 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", root->word);
        if(root->left == NULL)
        {
            root->left = addNode(token);
            printf("left add: %s\n", token);

        }

        else
        {
            printf("going left\n");
            insert(root->left, token);
        }
    }

    else if(strcmp(token, root->word) > 0)
    {
        if(root->right == NULL)
        {
            root->right = addNode(token);
            printf("right add: %s\n", token);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("going right\n");
            insert(root->right, token);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("updating count: %s\n", token);
        root->count = root->count + 1;
    }
}

struct node* addNode(char *token)
{
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    temp->word = token;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: There is no way anyone can help you without seeing the rest of your code. Specifically the `addNode` and `insert` functions. See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It was _better_ without the rest of the code.

Comment: I stand corrected and the question had also be added to since the time of the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Program is 90% correct. Here are your problems:

- `strtok()` uses some static buffer. It will always return a pointer to the same region of memory. This is why you feel like your top node changes every time. Just duplicate the parsed strings as well.
- you forget to initialize the count of every node! You will run into trouble sooner or later unless you fix that as well.

  ```
  struct node* addNode(char *token)
  {
      struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

      temp->word = strdup(token);
      temp->left = NULL;
      temp->right = NULL;
      temp->count = 0;

      return temp;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you! this fixed it but I get the error "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" do you know how to get rid of it?

Comment: To start, try to move int main() at the bottom of the file

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the variable `root` is passed to the function `insert` as a value, instead of a reference. As a value it can't be modified.

Fix:

```
 void insert(struct node **_root, char *token)
 {
      struct node *root = *_root; /* ADDED */
      if(strcmp(token, root->word) < 0)
      {
         printf("%s\n", root->word);
         if(root->left == NULL)
         {
            root->left = addNode(token);
            printf("left add: %s\n", token);
         }
         else
         {
            printf("going left\n");
            insert(&root->left, token);    // MODIFIED
         }
     }
    else if(strcmp(token, root->word) > 0)
    {
         if(root->right == NULL)
         {
             root->right = addNode(token);
             printf("right add: %s\n", token);
         } 
         else
         {
             printf("going right\n");
             insert(&root->right, token);    // MODIFIED
         }
     }
     else
     { 
         printf("updating count: %s\n", token);
         root->count = root->count + 1;
     }
     *_root = root;
 }

 insert(&root, token);
```

Comment: forgot to mention my struct is  struct node {
 char* word;
 int count;
 struct node* left;
 struct node* right;
}; what would the fix be in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the simplest way to write the `insert` function (at the cost of multiple overwriting children pointers with themselves) is:

```
    struct node* insert(struct node* nd, const char* token)
    {
        int cmp;

        if(nd == NULL)
        {
            printf("add: %s\n", token);
            return addNode(token);
        }

        cmp = strcmp(token, nd->word);
        if(cmp < 0)
            nd->left = insert(nd->left, token);
        else if(cmp > 0)
            nd->right = insert(nd->right, token);
        else
        {
            printf("updating count: %s\n", token);
            nd->count ++;
        }

        return nd;
    }
```

then in `main`:

```
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        for( token = strtok(buffer, del); token != NULL;
            token = strtok(NULL, del))
        {   
            root = insert(root, token);
        }
    }
```